# D3.js Force Layout: Possible to Have "Resting State" be a Specific Shape?

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a dashboard (in Ruby) with rotating views where each set of data includes a D3 visualization.

For the final visualization, I want to pull the circles into a heart shape.  I can use a force layout to pull them into a circle (similar to the Obama Budget example), but I haven't had success modifying that into other shapes.

I've read through all the d3 force layout Q&As on Stack Overflow as well as going through related D3 tutorials online.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to do this with D3 (or another tool/library)?

Potential options I'm currently researching:
1) Custom svg "canvass" shape
2) Append to heart-shaped div (found one made with :before/:after pseudo selectors but it currently will only display nodes in the before section)

Comment: Maybe it will work if you use the cardioid equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid